# Connecting ViewController causes SpriteKit to terminate app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit

I have a SpriteKit game, but now I'm working on making a menu. I decided to try to make these menus in a normal way, using `Storyboards` and `UIViewController`s.

However, this is proving to be very difficult.

I added a new `UIViewController`, and set it as the *initial viewcontroller*. This causes no problems. However, as soon as I hook this up to a completely basic `UIViewController` file (`FirstMenuViewController.m`), with no edits or additions, `ViewController.m` seems to freeze up at `if(!skView.scene){`.
I'm getting this error:

```
-[UIView scene]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x170164980
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView scene]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x170164980'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x187f7f100 0x1944881fc 0x187f83db4 0x187f81ae0 0x187ea178c 0x1001012ec 0x18af42f90
....
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

What I don't get is why `ViewController.m` is even called, as there is no connection to that file from my `FirstMenuViewController` which is set as the *initial viewcontroller*.

Could someone please explain to me what is going on here?

Comment: Your skView is not an SKView. It's a UIView, so it doesn't have a scene property.

Comment: @0x141E But I don't call the `ViewController` at all, I don't get why it even runs. And what should I do to resolve this?

Comment: Does your storyboard look like -> FirstMenuViewController with no connection to ViewController? Also, did you correctly set the Custom Class field of the first view controller in storyboard?

Comment: @0x141E Yes there is no connection between `FirstMenuViewController` and `ViewController`. I have not changed anything for the original `ViewController`, it's just as it was when I started the SpriteKit project from the template.

Comment: @0x141E The weird part is that if I don't assign a custom class to `FirstMenuViewController`, there is no problem. However if I do assign a custom class (without any custom code), it causes this error.

Comment: What did you add to FirstMenuViewController?

Comment: @0x141E Nothing, it's completely empty except for the standard `UIViewController` stuff (`initWithNibName`, `viewDidLoad`, `didReceiveMemoryWarning`). I have not added anything to these methods either.

Comment: I figured it out! Turns out I was subclassing `ViewController` (the `SpriteKit ViewController`), instead of `UIViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was subclassing the `ViewController` supplied by the `SpriteKit`-template instead of `UIViewController` when creating my `FirstMenuViewController`